# Is there any way to check in codename one if the user actually send an email message through the native email client or canceled ?

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the native email client delegation to send an email from condename one.

```
 Message m = new Message(message);
 Display.getInstance().sendMessage(data.getToEmails().toArray(new String[0]), data.getTitle(), m);
```

Is there a way to check if the user actually sent the email or canceled, when the codename one app is regaining control ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to check that. You can use the cloud email API or send thru an email proxy address as a workaround.